# How to set a navigation bar in the bottom of a page in react native?

Tags: react-native, navbar, footer, bottomnavigationview

How can we set a Navigation Bar at the bottom of the page in react native using View and components (if you want)!! with any tag of react-native npm - (/or else) you want!!

EX:

The Page Home :

----Header----

```
   ---- your tags (Screens)----
```

----Footer----

let us to do this -->-->-->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let us use this tag (View) then set styles on it.

...

```
 return (
        <View  style={styles.parantTagStyle}>
            <View>
                {
                    this.chechreturnedScreen()
                }
            </View>

            <View style={styles.footerTagStyle}>
                <TabBottom navigatorFunction={this.navPages} headerTitle={this.state.headerTitle} />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
```

and use this style :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
parantTagStyle: {
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    flex:1


},
footerTagStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,

},
```

});

...